# ClamWin Antivirus update on Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, azure, clam

I am trying to update ClamWin on my Windows Azure Virtual Machine. Windows has given popup like Your clamwin has update and when i click on update it will give me error like your update is failed check on clamwin scanlog file.

When i checked into log file, it is giving me error like,

```
ClamAV update process started at Tue Feb 21 06:14:34 2017 
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED! 
WARNING: Local version: 0.99.1 Recommended version: 0.99.2 
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav 
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer) 
WARNING: Can't get information about database.clamav.net: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution 
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-21468.cdiff from database.clamav.net 
WARNING: Can't get information about database.clamav.net: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution 
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-21468.cdiff from database.clamav.net 
ERROR: Can't get information about database.clamav.net: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution 
ERROR: getpatch: Can't download daily-21468.cdiff from database.clamav.net 
WARNING: Incremental update failed, trying to download daily.cvd 
ERROR: Can't get information about database.clamav.net: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution 
ERROR: Can't download daily.cvd from database.clamav.net 
Giving up on database.clamav.net... 
Update failed. Your network may be down or none of the mirrors listed in c:\users\talent~1\appdata\local\temp\30\tmp9ry1gs is working.
```

And My site is live and ClamWin is on my windows azure Virtual Machine and i can not take any risk about this.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Could you `ping database.clamav.net` on Azure VM? Do you configure firewall rules block VM access `database.clamav.net`?

Comment: when i ping database.clamav.net then i got this kind of details

Pinging db.uk.clamav.net [81.91.100.173] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 81.91.100.173: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=53
Reply from 81.91.100.173: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=53
Reply from 81.91.100.173: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=53
Reply from 81.91.100.173: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=53

Ping statistics for 81.91.100.173:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 10ms

Comment: Hi Maitri Do you check this [link](http://forums.clamwin.com/viewtopic.php?t=4397)

Comment: Hi Walter i updated  manually that 3 files 1)Main.cvd 2)bytecode.cvd 3)daily.cvd  in db folder of ClamWin and now in logs file this is appearing

Comment: WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.99.1 Recommended version: 0.99.2
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
daily.cvd is up to date (version: 23101, sigs: 1650084, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 290, sigs: 55, f-level: 63, builder: neo)